# Unlimited arguments in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Can a JavaScript function take unlimited arguments?
Something like this:

```
testArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5...);
```

I am trying:

```
var arr = [];
function testArray(A) {
    arr.push(A);
}
```

But this doesn't work (output is only the first argument). Or the only way is:

```
function testArray(a, b, c, d, e...) {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: As an alternative, you could have one parameter - "unlimited" container such as array (or object) and then just pass everything as array, even if there is only `...([one_arg])`...

Comment: Note that to directly answer the question, [No you can't.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's a weird "magic" variable you can reference called "arguments":

```
function manyArgs() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    alert(arguments[i]);
}
```

It's *like* an array, but it's not an array.  In fact it's so weird that you really shouldn't use it much at all.  A common practice is to get the values of it into a *real* array:

```
function foo() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  // ...
```

In that example, "args" would be a normal array, without any of the weirdness.  There are all sorts of nasty problems with "arguments", and in ECMAScript 5 its functionality will be curtailed.

*edit* — though using the `.slice()` function sure is convenient, it turns out that passing the `arguments` object out of a function causes headaches for optimization, so much so that functions that do it may not get optimized at all. The simple, straightforward way to turn `arguments` into an array is therefore

```
function foo() {
  var args = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) args[i] = arguments[i];
  // ...
}
```

[More about `arguments` and optimization.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)

Comment: There is nothing "magic" or weird about it, the arguments object is defined in ECMA-262. The only similarity it has with an array is that it's length property is one more than its highest numeric property name. Other than that, it's just an object with properties.

Comment: I was being poetic :-)  And the "arguments" variable *is* weird - it's also got things like the "callee" property.

Comment: @SmartLemon I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean. I was not trying to be unhelpful. Americans have no understanding of that expression beyond "extracting urine from it".

Comment: Sorry xD. I guess its not the common expression around there. Its like making fun of it. In this case it is like you are making fun of the question as if we should know it anyway.

Comment: @SmartLemon ah I see :-)  Well I wasn't really making fun of the question; the `arguments` object really is strange, and the designer of the language himself considers it to be a mistake now.

Comment: Here in this its explained in detail
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145032/whats-the-use-of-array-prototype-slice-callarray-0

Answer (score 35):

As of ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6) we also have access to [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) that give us a slightly cleaner way to manage arguments:

```
function foo(a, b, ...others) {
    console.log("a and b are ", a, b);

    for (let val of others) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

At the time of this writing, this is supported by Chrome 47+, Firefox 15+, and Edge. The feature is also available via both [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org/) transpiling down to ES5.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Especially the MDN link, I just couldnt remember the name of it. :)

Answer (score 10):

With ECMAScript 6, you can use rest of arguments syntax:

```
const testArray = (...args) => {
    console.log(args);
};

testArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some legacy methods but I prefer the `ES6` and newer versions, So if I wanna implement this, I wrote it like below:

```
const func = (...arg) => console.log(arg);
```

Simple and cutting edge of tech.

Comment: This is not quite valid JavaScript. I recommend the other answers to this question for an explanation of this feature.

Comment: @LucienGreathouse, thanks for your comment, I added parenthesis, it works now, sorry for my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript ES5

```
function testArray(){
    for(index = 0; index < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[index])
    }
}
```

Javascript ES6

```
const testArray = (...arg) => console.log(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toArray() {
   return arguments;
}

var myargs = toArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The `arguments` keyword is available in every js function

Comment: `arguments` is not of "type" `Array`, its just a sort of "iterable", and that is pretty lame on JS side.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
function testArray() {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just "cast" it, saving you the ugly loop:

```
var getArguments = function() {
    return arguments;
};

var foo = getArguments(1,2,3,4);

// console.log(foo.slice()); => TypeError: foo.slice is not a function

var foo = Object.values(foo); 

console.log(foo); // => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

foo.push(5);

console.log(foo); // => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const outputDiv=document.querySelector('.output');
const output=(...x)=>{
    return outputDiv.innerHTML=x;
}

output(1,2,3,4,['hello',5,6],true,null);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript Practice</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
        body{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; background-color: #060606;}
        .center{height:100vh; width: 100%; display: grid;align-items:center;justify-content: center;}
        .output{font-size: 15px;color: rgb(59, 59, 255);font-weight: 200;}
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class='output'></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this solves the problem, see [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)