# How to pass unlimited arguments and one or two parameters to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass multiple and unlimited `arguments` and one or two parameters to a function?

Example:

```
function myFunction(_id, _class, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, etc...){
    console.log($(_id).html());
    console.log($(_class).html());

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        alert(args[i]);
    }
}

myFunction("#myDiv",".mySpan", "Hello World!", "Bonjour le monde!", "Hola mundo!", "Ciao mondo", "Hallo Welt!", "etc");
```

Comment: and [Unlimited arguments in a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6396046/218196)

Comment: Is not a duplicate, my question is different. I want to pass "parameters" + argoments in a jQuery/JavaScript function.

Comment: Given the fact that ES6 introduces a new parameter syntax for that, I retracted my close vote. I think you should edit title though, to better reflect the question.

Comment: I changed the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). It is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

```
function myFunction(_id, _class){
    console.log($(_id).html());
    console.log($(_class).html());

    for(var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
}

myFunction("#myDiv",".mySpan", "Hello World!", "Bonjour le monde!", "Hola mundo!", "Ciao mondo", "Hallo Welt!", "etc");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y6kh8/)

Answer (score 7):

More of a future answer:

ECMAScript 6 introduces a new parameter syntax specifically for that, [the "rest" parameter](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3arest_parameters). The rest parameter has to be preceded by three dots (`...`) and must be the last parameter in the list.

Example:

```
function myFunction(_id, _class, ...args){
    console.log($(_id).html());
    console.log($(_class).html());

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        alert(args[i]);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y29Wm/) (only FF15+)

---

So far, [only Firefox 15+ supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/rest_parameters).

Comment: This will be useful when all browsers get around to supporting it. This feature will make a lot of code a lot more readable. Thanks for including it as an answer :)