# Invoke a JavaScript function with parameter in a function

Tags: javascript

Today, I saw the following code below:

```
log_execution_time = require('./utils').log_execution_time;
var fib = function fib(n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};

var timed_fib = log_execution_time(fib);
timed_fib(5);

>>> Execution time: 1.166ms
```

I am curious about function `log_execution_time`. I don't know how it is.

You can see the input of `log_execution_time` is a function. How can it call the function with parameter? But all of the methods from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) need a parameter when calling a function. I assume:

```
var log_execution_time = function (input_function){
console.time("Execution time");
// input_function
console.timeEnd("Execution time");
}
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: You can pass functions as stand-alone un-invokes object or _anonymous functions_ (other languages call this LAMBDAS). All you need to do with a passed function is invoke it with its variable name. So this would work: `function exec(a){ a(); } exec( function(){ alert('Anonymous but still alerting!'); } );`. Read up on the basics of `functions` before continuing, heres a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: Functions are first class objects in _JavaScript_. You can set identifiers and pass their references around just the same as any other object. `log_execution_time(fib);` does not invoke `fib`, it passes a reference to `fib` into the `log_execution_time` function as the first argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I think the OP is specifically about how the `5` parameter gets passed to the function `input_function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275331/invoke-a-javascript-function-with-parameter-in-a-function/35275635#comment58262539_35275464)

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. You can set identifiers and pass their references around just the same as any other object.

1. `log_execution_time(fib);` does not invoke `fib`, it passes a reference to fib into the `log_execution_time` function as the first argument. This means the internals can reference `fib`
2. `timed_fib` is a function which can reference the closure from that invocation of `log_execution_time` due to **when** it was created, so it can hence invoke the reference to `fib` as desired

Here is a simple example;

```
function log(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

function wrap(fn) {
    return function () { // some anonymous function to be our wrapper
        console.log('Wrapped:');
        fn.apply(this, arguments); // this line invokes `fn` with whatever arguments 
                                   // that were passed into the anonymous function
    };
}

var foo = wrap(log);
foo('Hello World'); // logs
// Wrapped:
// Hello World
```

We could also have used the more usual way to invoke `fn`, for example `fn("fizz buzz");`, instead of `.apply` but that would mean we needed to know more about how to invoke `fn`, which could have been anything

---

Useful stuff:

- [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Thanks for useful tips :D

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [function currying](http://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/), in this case the function is being curried with a parameter that also happens to be a function.  It may look something like this:

```
function logTime(f) {
    return function() {
        var s = new Date();
        var r = f.apply(null, arguments);
        var e = new Date();
        console.log('Time taken ' + (e-s));
        return r;
    }
}

function numberlogger(n) {
    console.log("logged number: " + n)
};

var timedlogger = logTime(numberlogger);

console.log(timedlogger(2));
```

We call `logTime`, passing in `numberlogger` as an argument.  Functions in JavaScript are objects and can be passed around like anything else.  The `logTime` function returns a *different* function that is then stored in `timedlogger`.  When we invoke `timedlogger`, we're actually invoking the function that `logTime` returned.  That uses a couple of variables to keep track of the start and end times for timing, but uses [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (which every function in js has) to call the original function (`numberlogger`) whilst passing in any [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) supplied.

Comment: @DavinTryon No, [it seems to work without doing so](https://jsfiddle.net/yug06q3y/) (at least in chrome)

Comment: If you are talking about `Array.prototyle.slice`, then no. Slice will only convert the arguments object to an array, but `apply` will happily take the arguments object from another function

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on Functions in Javascript. Here's a nice article from the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) which is in my opinion, a much better resource than w3schools

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

To answer your question though, functions in javascript are first class citizens, and what that means is that you can think of them as any other object (string,boolean,number etc). They can be saved in variables and they can be passed as arguments into other functions.

In your example, `log_execution_time` will actually **return a function** which is essentially a wrapper around the `fib` function that gets passed to it

Comment: I think the OP is specifically about how the `5` parameter gets passed to the function `input_function`.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be like this:

```
var log_execution_time = function (input_function){
var f=function(args)
{
     var t1=new Date().getTime();
     input_function(arguments);
     console.warn("Execution time:" +(new Date().getTime()-t1).toString());
}
return f;
}
```

Comment: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l` that is a bit awkward,  how about if I have more than `l` args?

Comment: use arguments instead.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396046/unlimited-arguments-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: Gotta love ES2015. Turn that ugly thing to `(...args)`