# JavaScript: Create a function defineFirstArg that accepts a function and an argument; Accept More Arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments, higher-order-functions

Create a function defineFirstArg that accepts a function and an argument. Also, the function being passed in will accept at least one argument. defineFirstArg will return a new function that invokes the passed-in function with the passed-in argument as the passed-in function's first argument. Additional arguments needed by the passed-in function will need to be passed into the returned function.

Below is my code:

```
const defineFirstArg = (inputFunc, arg) => {

  return function (argTwo) {
    return inputFunc(arg, argTwo)
  }
}
```

But it's failing the last test spec:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third test condition says arguments, not an argument so maybe  you will need to try spread operator instead

```
    const defineFirstArg = (inputFunc, arg) => {

      return function (...addtionalArgs) {
        return inputFunc(arg, ...addtionalArgs)
      }
    }
  f2 = defineFirstArg(console.log,"x")
  f2("y","z",'f')
  //x y z f
```

to spread the parameters and execute the function passed on an unlimited number of parameters

Comment: where do I add ...arg?

Comment: i edited the answer to be more clear I hope it is the needed

Comment: When I run your code above, it produces TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Comment: after the last edit, i tested the code and it gives logical result to the behaviour described but ... operator is new es6 feature so it if the javascript version is older you can user `arguments` instead ..to make the second function accept unlimited number of arguments check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396046/unlimited-arguments-in-a-javascript-function