# what does "var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));" really do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply, slice, getelementsbytagname

I don't understand how this works:

```
var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
```

It creates an empty array but I don't completely get the rest. What do `slice` and `apply` really do together in this script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work)

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` and similar DOM methods return an array-like structure, a node list, instead of a true array. This is a common trick to convert it into a true array. It is also commonly used with the `arguments` special variable, another array-like structure. The `slice` method of the Array object would normally expect an array, and returns an array, but this way you can pass in something that is not technically an array. A slightly more readable, and arguably better version is this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
```

Comment: I could be mistaken but the second version pulls the method straight from the prototype as opposed to creating an empty array and then going up the prototype chain to find the slice method.

Comment: Looks like the improvement is negligible: http://jsperf.com/array-slices  -- but I'd still argue it is a little more readable.

Comment: cecchi, the "apply" part returns a nodelist, ok. but what about slice? what does it do with this nodelist?

Comment: Well the `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList. The `apply` method lets you pass in custom arguments and context to a method or function, in this case we are making the NodeList the context for the `slice` method. `slice` simply returns part of an array, but since we use it without any arguments it just returns the whole array, effectively transforming its data type.

Comment: Without `apply` there isn't a way to call `slice` on the NodeList because that method is part of the Array prototype.

Answer (score 0):

This basically converts the nodeList object retrieved from the getElementsByTagName into regular javascript array, to be able to use array methods on it.