# why does array slice convert javascript arguments to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, slice

Why does applying the slice method to the javascript `arguments` value as follows `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` convert it to an array? If slice is used on arrays, and `arguments` is not an array, then how does this work? Is it just a special case when `slice` is applied to arguments?

Comment: hrm. yeah. Why wouldn't the conversion be a feature of the arguments object, instead of slice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7056925/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [EcmaScript specification on `Array.prototype.slice`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10):

> *NOTE* The `slice` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the `slice` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

And so, `slice` works on every object that has a `length` property (like `Arguments` objects). And even for those that do not, it then just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

Right, this is a trick that takes advantage of the fact that arguments are an enumerable list. It works on other enumerable lists too (for example nodelists).