# What does arguments reference when used as an argument?

Tags: javascript

Here is _.extend from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
  // Extend a given object with all the properties in passed-in object(s).
  _.extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

The function `call` expects a this value followed by a list of arguments.

If the only argument passed is '1', then slice will return an array omitting the first item.

However, how can arguments be used as a this value as defined my MDN.

MDN

[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: Any object can be used as a `this` value, even `null`.

Comment: duplicate of [why does array slice convert javascript arguments to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327339/why-does-array-slice-convert-javascript-arguments-to-array)

Comment: `arguments` is an array-like object, containing a reference to each argument passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arguments as the this value applies the function to arguments.  It would be like doing arguments.slice(1), except you can't because arguments is technically not an array.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing it always references, the arguments passed to the containing function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "this" is implied. Sometimes you have to "force" a fake list to apply to some Array prototypes else it won't work.

I might be misunderstanding your questions, if so - I apologize.