# what does array.prototype.length give me an error

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between array.length and array.prototype.length?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) they should be functionally equivalent. What is the difference? When should I use one over the other? Why does the latter give me an error?

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(a.length);//5
console.log(a.prototype.length);// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: "*functionally equivalent*" does not mean they are the same thing. They are totally separate things that **behave** the same.

Comment: `prototype` properties are typically only members of `function`s for when they're used as constructors, such as `Array.prototype` and `new Array()`. You won't find the property on the instances being created, unless you set it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `Array.prototype` and `a.prototype` (where `a` is an array).

There is no such thing as `a.prototype`. The instances don't have this property, only their constructor function does (the Javascript engine attaches it to the instance in some other, engine-specific and unstandardized way).

Comment: @thomas: There is no standard way to get the prototype of an object that has already been created. If `a.prototype` works in some environment that is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @Jon AFAIK also you can get an `Array` from `a` with the `a.constructor` property

Comment: @thomas `[].constructor === Array` should return true

Comment: How can `Array.prototype(.length)` be "usefully used"?

Comment: I don't know about uses for `length` but you can use `Array.prototype.slice` to make an array out of `arguments`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327339/why-does-array-slice-convert-javascript-arguments-to-array

Comment: Why does the Chrome console give me many autocomplete suggestions when I type `Array.prototype.` (`filter`, `forEach`, `hasOwnProperty`, etc), but when I type `Array.prototype.length` it prints `0`?

Answer (score 3):

[*Array.prototype*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4) is an Array whose length is initially set to 0.

Array instances have their own, special, self–adjusting *length* property so when you do:

```
var a = [];
console.log(a.length);
```

you are seeing the value of *a*'s length property, it's not inherited from its `[[Prototype]]`. When you do:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.length);
```

you are seeing the length of the *Array.prototype* array, which is a different object with its own length property. Changing the length of an Array instance's length does not affect the length of *Array.prototype*, and *vice versa*.

Comment: regarding you link, what does "whose initial value is +0" mean?

Comment: It just means that initially it's length is zero (i.e. it's an empty Array).

Comment: what is `[[Prototype]]` in the braces?

Comment: The ECMAScript specification uses that notation to indicate an object's internal `[[Prototype]]` rather than the public *prototype* such as that associated with a constructor, see [*ES5 table 8*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2).