# Why is length property owned by an array object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-chain

There are other examples, but for the sake of simplicity let's take the `length` property, what's that doing here:

```
[].hasOwnProperty("length")
//==> true
```

As we know, array's `length` property resides on `Array.prototype` so it's readily accessible from any array instance just by walking up the prototype chain, why copy it down? Has it something to do with the specific implementation in the browser? (code example above executed in chrome console). Even MDN clearly says that: "...methods and properties are not copied from one object to another in the prototype chain. They are accessed by walking up the chain..."

Comment: "*As we know, array's length property resides on `Array.prototype`*" - uh, not really, it doesn't.

Comment: If the property were on the prototype object, then how could it possibly be different for an array instance with 2 elements and an array with 200?

Comment: @Pointy I assume you could implement that with a getter on the prototype that reads the length from `this`? But that doesn't seem like it would be as efficient as just having each array store its own length, and may not have worked in early ES versions either.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes that would be possible but the `.length` property long preceeds the getter facility; `.length` has been there since the 90s. It's an instance property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: because every array instance has a different `.length` value.

The `.length` property could have been a getter/setter that would be inherited from a shared prototype object, but the initial design of JavaScript went with  a data property that is updated automatically with element creation/removal.

> `length` property resides on `Array.prototype`

There exists an `Array.prototype.length` property, but only because [`Array.prototype` is itself an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23652338/1048572). Notice that its value is `0` - you wouldn't want that to be inherited to all arrays.

Comment: "Array.prototype is itself an array" that was the missing point – another knowledge gap closed, thanks

Comment: @zepeersGily Yeah, it's a really weird design decision, and hardly known because it's not really important for anything. It probably wouldn't be an array if JS was designed today, but it is the way it is and can't be changed for compatibility reasons.

Comment: See also [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306692/1048572) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270097/1048572) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34106934/1048572) touching upon the subject.