# How is this function able to return a single object?

Tags: javascript, arguments, slice

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); //Here is my problem
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

I found this example of the use of the slice function online and would like some help understanding how the call() function is able to access each item which is passed to list through the use of the "arguments" property.

I don't understand how passing the single "arguments" property as the function context to slice() works. Am I missing some recursion going on in there somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function turns the provided arguments object into an array.

When a function's call method is called, then *this* within the function is set to the supplied object. Another way to call it is:

```
[].slice.call(arguments);
```

so inside the slice method, *this* isn't the empyt array at the start of the expression, but the *arguments* object.

This isn't a good idea if the object passed is not a native object (e.g. a DOM object like a NodeList or similar) as it will fail on some browsers in use. Also, *this* isn't "context", it's simply one parameter of a function's execution context.