# is it possible to add some new syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, operator-overloading

Is it possible to add some new syntax into javascript? Like if I want it to have a synatx like:

`mul>10>20` and it result `200` or if say `mul(2)(3)` and it result as 6 ? It is possible? I saw  similar question somewhere to do this? So I am not sure if it is possible or not?  If not in JS is it possible in other languages like C, Java, Python ? My understanding is that all these languages are only able to add some functionality for new objects and even those new objects can only have operators and syntax that a language itself already have? So am I correct or this is possible to add new syntax to these langauges?

Comment: You can do the second one natively (currying), not the first one, unless you do some unnecessary `eval` parsing.

Comment: And it would look ugly if you attempt to parse it somehow. But checkout Coffeescript or other languages that make JavaScript with a new syntax. You could fork and extend.

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with Lisp macros... :-)

Comment: Take a look at a good lisp book. I think you'll like what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python

```
mul(2)(3)
```

means *call `mul` with argument `2`, then call the `return` value from that with argument `3`* (which assumes that it's a function). You can't redefine that syntax, but you could make your function work with it:

```
def mul(arg):
    return lambda x: x * arg
```

To allow chaining (i.e. `mul (2)(3)(4)`) I would go for a `class`:

```
import operator

class op(object):

    def __init__(self, op, arg):
        self.op = op
        self.value = self._get_val(arg)

    def _get_val(self, arg):
        try:
            return arg.value
        except AttributeError:
            return arg

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __call__(self, arg):
        self.value = self.op(self.value, 
                             self._get_val(arg))
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.value = self.op(self.value, 
                             -1 * self._get_val(key))
        return self


class mul(op):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(mul, self).__init__(operator.mul, arg)
```

I have added a bonus feature, square brackets make the argument negative (`mul(2)[3] == -6`). This only *pretends* to `return` a number; I leave implementing the rest of the necessary [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#operators) as an exercise for the reader.

You couldn't make `mul>x>y` do anything other than return `x > y` (`True` or `False`), as the function object `mul` will evaluate as larger than any integers.

Comment: what if I want these arguments to be recursive not just two ?

Comment: Good question; answer edited. Note that this all means more work for you and harder-to-read code!

Comment: it says super() take atleast one argument 0 given

Comment: My code is for Python 3.x, you may have to make some adjustments for 2.x

Comment: There was only one change needed for 2.x (in `mul.__init__()`), which I've now made

Comment: awesome help, awesome followup and nice guide: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#operators :)

Answer (score 12):

The answer to your broader question is write *into* the language you're working with, meaning aim to solve your problems with the tools that are available to you.

However, the second example you've given is actually already a fairly common pattern known as *currying*.  You can extend Javascript to achieve this with the following:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

So assuming `mul(a, b)` is:

```
function mul(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

You can use `mul.curry(2)(3)`

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Za68j/)

For a much more in-depth explanation of this design pattern, check out http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but partial application != curry.

Comment: if anyone want to see how Array.prototype.slice.call() works then it can be seen at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work

Comment: but how can it be argument range independent ? means i don't know how whether it will be `mul(2)(3)` or `mul(2)(3)(1)(9)`

Answer (score 0):

Currying will allow you to do this:

```
function mul(num1) {
  return function (num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
  }
}

mul(2)(3); // 6
```

Multiple argument version (need to specify end of args with empty parens):

```
function mul (num1) {
  var vals = [num1];
  var fn = function (num2) {
    if (num2) {
      vals.push(num2);
      return fn;
    }else{
      var res = 1;
      vals.forEach(function (el) {
        res *= el;
      });
      return res;
    }
  }

  return fn;
}

console.log(mul(2)(3)(4)()); // 24
```

Comment: I already did this but it will never know when it is last argument, so can never do anything that is required at end. :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have more than 2 arguments? If so, I made an edit to show how you can do that.