# How might one change the syntax of python list indexing?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, syntax, indexing

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753569/function-returning-reference-to-itself-python/), it received a comment about how you could do something like this:

```
>>> def a(n):
        print(n)
        return a
>>> b = a(3)(4)(5)
3
4
5
```

Is it possible to use this or similar concepts to make it possible to index lists like `my_list(n)` instead of `my_list[n]`?

Comment: You ask good questions. I like your curiosity

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831647/is-it-possible-to-add-some-new-syntax-in-javascript/20831768#20831768) interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to use a custom class, and give it a [`__call__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) to make it callable. A subclass of `list` would do nicely here:

```
class CallableList(list):
    def __call__(self, item):
        return self[item]
```

You cannot use this to *assign* to an index, however, only item *access* works. Slicing would require you to use to create a `slice()` object:

```
a = CallableList([1, 2, 3])
a(2)
a(slice(None, 2, None))

nested = CallableList([1, 2, CallableList([4, 5, 6])])
nested(2)(-1)
```

For anything more, you'd have to create a custom Python syntax parser to build an AST, then compile to bytecode from there.

Comment: How would we access a 2d list using `my_matrix(x)(y)` instead of `my_matrix[x][y]`?

Comment: @Scorpion_God: You'd store a `CallableList()` object in a `CallableList()`, just like you'd store a regular list inside another to get a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

the parentheses in my_list() are treated as a function call. If you want, you could write your own class that wraps a list and overwrite the **call** method to index into the list.

```
class MyList(object):

    def __init__(self, alist):
        self._list = alist

    def __call__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]

>>> mylist = MyList(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
>>> mylist(3)
'd'
>>> mylist(4)
'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function:

```
def make_callable(some_list):
    return lambda x: some_list[x]

original_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
callable_list = make_callable(original_list)

print(callable_list(1)) # Prints 2
```