# Python: Use altered syntax to access elements from n-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, syntax, indexing

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754775/how-might-one-change-the-syntax-of-python-list-indexing/), I expanded upon the accepted answer to make it work on 2-dimensional lists:

```
class List(list):
    def __call__(self, i):
        def call(j):
            return self[i][j]
        return call
```

And 3-dimensional lists:

```
class List(list):
    def __call__(self, i):
        def call2(j):
            def call3(k):
                return self[i][j][k]
            return call3
        return call2
```

But how would this class be implemented for n-dimensional lists?

Comment: Calls are applied *after* returning the object from the previous expression. You cannot up front know if the return value is going to be called. You can use store your `List(2)` result somewhere, and decide to call it later on, or not at all, for example.

Answer (score 5):

You can return the 'callable list' type if the indexed value is itself a [`Sequence` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence):

```
from collections import Sequence

class List(list):
    def __call__(self, i):
        res = self[i]
        if isinstance(res, Sequence) and not isinstance(res, str):
            res = type(self)(res)
        return res
```

This ensures that anything that *can* be addressed with the `[..]` indexing syntax can now be addressed with a `(..)` call syntax as well.

I exempted strings; these are sequences as well but you probably don't want to extend this to those values.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Sequence
>>> class List(list):
...     def __call__(self, i):
...         res = self[i]
...         if isinstance(res, Sequence) and not isinstance(res, str):
...             res = type(self)(res)
...         return res
... 
>>> a = List([[['foo']]])
>>> a(0)
[['foo']]
>>> a(0)(0)(0)
'foo'
```

Comment: This will convert strings to `List`s, which may or may not be the intended behaviour.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Just came to the same conclusion, already updated.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I was testing the code and discovered that I had forgotten `basestring` was removed. :-P

Comment: @eryksun: and there's `range()` as well. It all comes down to a choice as to what you want the call syntax to apply to.

Comment: Now I will always use this method when indexing lists. That way, anyone reading my code will have a _very clear_ understanding of what is happening. And it might make my code more readable to Malbolge programmers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge

Comment: @Scorpion_God: Ick, I need to have my irony meter adjusted, it appears.

Comment: @eryksun: lets hope so!