# Using 'self' with a square bracket

Tags: python

I was wondering whether or not I can use a square bracket like `self[avariable]`, so I have implemented `__getitem__`. The code which I have tried:

```
class myclass:
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self[index]

babe = myclass()
print babe[4]
```

When I run this it shows:

```
File "C:/Python27/df", line 3, in __getitem__
    return self[index]
```

recursively.

How can I use a variable like `self[name]` with `__getitem__` in Python?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually i post this question to find the exact working of using like self[avariable]..if its posible please post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class needs to have something to index, rather than `self`. For example, in this class `foo`, it has a member variable `data` which is a list. So the index operation could index out of the list `data` for example.

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.data = l

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

>>> a = foo([1,2,3])
>>> a[1]
2
```

Comment: @Cybr ..is there any way that i could use something like self[avariable] ?

Comment: `self[avariable]` will call `self.__getitem__(avariable)`, hence the loop you get stuck in. Inside `__getitem__` you need to decide where the data should really be coming from (`self.data`, in this example).

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you give me a code which uses like self.[avariable] ??..is this possible in python ,,then please post an example as answer

Comment: @lovemysql You keep asking the same thing over and over. Please read the responses people are telling you. `self[variable]` does not do what you think it does, you need something to actually index out of.

Comment: @Cyber see i just want to know if using like self[avariable] in any cases is posible ??

Comment: @Cyber see i just dont want to use data..without using it i want like self[avariable]..is this possible without using __getitem__

Comment: @lovemysql I will say this as clearly as possible: `self[avariable]` will try to index out of `self` using the `__getitem__` method. You need to define `__getitem__` with something meaningful to index from. To restate: `self[avariable]` will call the `__getitem__` method!!

Comment: @Cyber see just leave the __getitem__ ..just consider other cases wheather i can use  like self[avaribale]

Comment: You cannot "just leave the `getitem`"!!! That is the method that will be invoked by the `[]` operator! That is what we keep trying to tell you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple class to demonstrate the theory:

```
class Indexable(object):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("You indexed me with {}.".format(index))
```

In use, then:

```
>>> i = Indexable()
>>> i[12]
You indexed me with 12.
```

Here we can clearly see that `i[12]` resolves to `Indexable.__getitem__(i, 12)`.

This happens everywhere - even if you call `self[avariable]` inside an instance method (*including `__getitem__`*), you will end up calling `Indexable.__getitem__(self, avariable)`. This explains the infinite loop if you include `self[avariable]` inside `Indexable.__getitem__`.

This will always be the case in Python, you cannot redefine this syntax without rewriting it yourself. This is a "magic method", just like `str(instance)` calls `Class.__str__(instance)`.

---

In practice, you will generally want to define some useful behaviour for indexing, perhaps you want to fake `numpy`-style comma-separated indexing:

```
class NotArray(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data = self.data
        for ind in index:
            data = data[ind]
        return data
```

This can be used like:

```
>>> arr = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
>>> arr[1, 1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    arr[1, 1, 1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
>>> arr = NotArray([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
>>> arr[1, 1, 1]
8
```

Note that we have now defined a source for the data to be returned for a given index.

---

You could also use this to implement non-standard syntax, like I do in my answer to this question: [is it possible to add some new syntax in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20831647/3001761) But this is generally discouraged, as it will confuse readers of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myclass(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(myclass, self).__getitem__(key-1)

babe = myclass()
babe.append(1)
babe.append(2)
babe.append(3)
babe.append(4)
print babe[4]
```