# Why is the length property changing in my array-like object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through a tutorial on JavaScript's `call` and `apply` methods, and am confused by the behavior of an 'array-like object' used in the example:

```
var arrayLikeObj = {
    0: 'Marty',
    1: 78,
    2: 42,
    3: ['Tim', 'Eric', 'Phil'],
    length: 4
};
```

My understanding is that the length property here is wholly unrelated to the `Array.prototype.length` method, and was hard-coded in order to give the object it's necessary array-like properties.

However, when I `pop` the array-like object as such:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.pop.call(arrayLikeObj));
```

...it's length property has decreased!

```
console.log(arrayLikeObj) // Object {0: "Marty", 1: 78, 2: 42, length: 3}
```

How is this possible!?

Does `Array.prototype.length` somehow overwrite the existing length property in the object, turning it into a length method?

To further my confusion, when I declare an object without the hard-coded `length` property and call the same `pop` method:

```
var arrayLikeObj = {
        0: 'Marty',
        1: 78,
        2: 42,
        3: ['Tim', 'Eric', 'Phil']
    };

console.log(Array.prototype.pop.call(arrayLikeObj));
console.log(arrayLikeObj);
```

The returned object has been assigned a length of 0:

```
{0: "Marty", 1: 78, 2: 42, 3: Array[3], length: 0}
```

I am very interested in understanding what is happening here.

Comment: Because that's what that methods does. It is described to modify a `.length` property on the `this` object it was given. [ECMAScript 5 - 15.4.4.6  Array.prototype.pop](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.6)  If there's no `.length`, it gets a default `0` value. *"If len is zero,

   a. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments "length", 0, and true; b. return undefined"*

Comment: Note that most, if not all, of the `Array.prototype` methods have a version of the following: *"The `pop` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method."*

Comment: Related: [How does Array.prototype.slice.call() work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.pop` creates a `length` property for the object.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.6

It happens in steps 4.a and 5.d. In the second case you posted, note that the `[[Get]]` internal method returns `undefined` (since there is no `length` property), and `ToUint32(undefined)` first converts `undefined` to `NaN` and then converts `NaN` to `0`.