# Converting arguments to array but individual indices inaccessible

Tags: javascript

I need to write a swapping function. Assume an example input of [1,2]. This is what I have right now:

```
function swapValues() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(args[0]);

    var temp = args[0];
    args[0] = args[1];
    args[1] = temp;

    return args;
}
```

I'm not getting the desired swap functionality, so I put the console.log statement in to see what is happening. The problem is I'm getting [1 , 2] printed to the console, but I'm only expecting one. The values returned are not swapped.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work

Comment: it works for me : `swap(1,2)` yields `[2,1]`

Comment: Should you input be `[1, 2]` or simply `1, 2`?  my guess would be @ValentinWaeselynck has it right.

Comment: the input is an array. I modified the function to take an array as a parameter and then operated on / returned that array. It passed the test suite, but i can see how it could be made more general by just taking in anything the user provides and using ....slice.call to convert it to an array and swap those values

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel thanks, I actually just read that before posting this. I think the test suite I was provided with just didn't provide clear instructions for this function.

Comment: you can simply use apply() on it (as written) to process arrays

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `Array.protoype.reverse`? I would do this:

```
function swapValues() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args.reverse();
}
```