# Plupload reverse order of uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I want to reverse order of uploading file in plupload.

Tried:

```
FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
    files = files.reverse();
    plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        up.start();
    });
},
```

But it does the same.

I want to reverse the order of file uploadin.

Eg:

User selects: Img1,Img2,Img3,Img4

Plupload will upload: Img4,Img3,Img2,Img1

Is there any method to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: is `files` an object?

Comment: @AustinAllover Yes! It will show the list as Img4,Img3,Img2,Img1 but will upload from the end to beginning (Img1,Img2,Img3,Img4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object not appear to have `.reverse()` method . Try utilizing `.slice()` , `.call()` to convert `files` to `Array` , then call `.reverse()` method on array of `File` objects. See [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work/)

```
FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
    var reversed = Array.prototype.slice.call(files).reverse();
    plupload.each(reveresed, function(file) {
        up.start();
    });
},
```

---

```js
    $("input").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files;
      var reversed = Array.prototype.slice.call(files).reverse();
      console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(files), reversed);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file" multiple />
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/531ozmn2/