# Why does this piece of javascript gives different results?

Tags: javascript, prototype, call, slice

```
function H() {

 }

H.prototype.K = function() {
      console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); //gives [20, 30, 40]
      console.log(Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1)); //gives []
   }

 H.prototype.K(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Why calling slice directly gives empty array? If I can call function K directly, why can't I call slice directly?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Given your call to `H.prototype.K(...)`, it seems you're not understanding some of the basics of how to use prototypal inheritance. That should very rarely be done.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work/7057090#7057090) may help give you a better understanding of why this is done.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1)` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.slice.call(Array.prototype, arguments, 1)`. Note that `call` always accepts a context as the first parameter. That should make it easier to track down the behavior..

Comment: Because `Array.prototype` is an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1)` appear to be calling `.slice()` on `Array.prototype`

See [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) , [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> `arr.slice([begin[, end]])`
>
> Parameters
>
> begin
>
> Zero-based index at which to begin extraction. As a negative index,
>   begin indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-2)
>   extracts the last two elements in the sequence. If begin is omitted,
>   slice begins from index 0.

---

```js
console.log(Array.prototype); // `[]` 
console.log(Array.prototype.slice()); // `[]`
console.log(Array.prototype.slice([10, 20, 30, 40], 1)); // `[]`
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call([10, 20, 30, 40] , 1)); // `[20, 30, 40]`
console.log([].slice([10, 20, 30, 40], 1)); // `[]`
console.log([].slice.call([10, 20, 30, 40] , 1)); // `[20, 30, 40]`
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function directly, it gets a different context. When called as a method the context is the `arguments` array, but when you call it directly the context will be the `Array.prototype` object.

The second call won't try to get items from the `arguments` array, it will try to get items from the `Array.prototype` array (which acts as an empty array), using `arguments` as first index and `1` as length.

Comment: The "context" will be `Array.prototype`, which is an Array (or looks enough like one).

Comment: Well, I saved arguments to args locally and executed slice on args, still got empty array.

Comment: @HarshSavla: How did you save the arguments to args? If you just assigned arguments to a variable then you just have another reference to the same object.