# How do i concat arrays with unknown amount of arguments

Tags: javascript, concatenation

So I have my function uniteUnique. It should get the arguments and concatonate them to a single array. If there would be a specific amount of arguments for example 3, i would implement it like the function bellow

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = [];
  var newArgs;
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
    newArgs = args[0].concat(args[1], args[2]);
  }
  return newArgs ;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]);
```

But what if uniteUnique function would have 2 arguments or any other number.

```
uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1])
```

How to make my function know how many arguments it should concatonate, and how would it be implemented inside the concat() function ?

EDIT:

Output should look like this:

`uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]])`  should return `[1,3,1,1,[5],2,`[4]]`and uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1])` should return `[1,2,3,5,2,1]`

Comment: Can you specify sample inputs and their respective outputs upon invoking `uniteUnique`?

Comment: How to you use the `arr` argument? And why do you return `arguments` and not `newArgs`?

Comment: @MarcoS I will edit it, but newArgs, would return only the last argument.

Comment: @gurvindrer372 i have included the second input uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1]) as an example of what could be used.

Comment: @Giedrius what should be the output for this input?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but: what about this simple solution?

```
function uniteUnique() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}
```

The `arguments` object is not really an `Array` instance, and does not have any of the Array methods. So, arguments.slice(...) will not work because the arguments object does not have the slice method.

Instead, `Arrays` do have this method, and because the `arguments` object is very similar (...) to an array, the two are compatible. This means that we can use array methods with the `arguments` object. And array methods will return arrays rather than other argument objects.

For a more throughtful explanation please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057090/709439) ...

**UPDATE** (to answer OP comment):

If you need *deep* merging, you can do:

```
function uniteUnique() {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays);
}
```

or even:

```
function uniteUnique() {
  return [].concat.apply([], arrays);
}
```

This should work since the dafaule value of `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` is `false`, so `concat()` acts **deeply**...

Comment: This did, the trick, could give a brief explanation of this ?

Comment: Of course, sorry... Just adding some explanation... :-)

Comment: Sorry it have not concatonated the arrays theyre still seperated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

According to your examples you want to flatten arguments array. In ES6 you can use [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get arguments array and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to flatten it:

```
function uniteUnique(...args) {
  return [].concat(...args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

You can access the arguments variable to loop through all arguments passed to a given function.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this like that,

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
   var myNewArray = [].concat.apply([], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  return myNewArray;
}
uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]) ;
```