# Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) vs. Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)

Tags: javascript, prototype

Previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work) have talked about how `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` work but I don't get why you're using `call` instead of `apply` when apply is used for array-like objects whereas `call` is used on lists of objects separated by commas. Isn't `arguments` an array-like object that should used `apply` instead of `call`?

Comment: Even if you used `apply` instead of `call`, `arguments` is the [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), not the `argsArray`, so it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: your link is broken, so can't tell if you're reading it right

Comment: Were you intending to link to this post? [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work)

Comment: The 1st argument passed to each method is the same. The difference between them is in the 2nd or further arguments. `.call(thisArg, arg0, arg1, ...)` vs. `apply(thisArg, argsList)`. The value given for `thisArg` becomes the value of `this` used by the function being invoked (`slice`).

Comment: Side note: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) was added to a recent edition of the language to in part replace this use of `slice`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between call and apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to pass arguments to slice in array instead of one by one, then there is a difference. You could do it this way

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  ---- our example arguments
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2, 5);
```

here you pass to slice method 2 and 5 and these are slice arguments to indicate that you want to get items at index 1 to item at index. 4. So most likely it will be 3, 4, 5.

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [2, 5]);
```

This does the same but arguments for slice can be passed in an array.

Comment: so if I don't pass any arguments, apply and call is the same?

Comment: Yes, then they work the same.

btw. If you dont pass any argument slice just copies the array - no matter if you call it or apply it.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is an array, then these are the same:

```js
// find the "slice" method of an array and call it with "x" as its "this" argument
x.slice();

// find the "slice" method of an array and call it with "x" as its "this" argument
Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
```

The first argument of `func.call` is this *this* argument, or, the value of `this` inside the function. The remaining arguments are the arguments of the function (in this case there are none).

The slice method, called with no arguments, simply creates a new array with the same contents. That's what we want to do when we do `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`, however, since `arguments` isn't an *array* and therefore has no `slice` method attach to itself, we have to use the second of the two methods to get the `slice` method of an *array*, and then apply that to something that's *not* an array:

```js
// find the "slice" method of an array and call it with "arguments",
// which is *not* an array, as its "this" argument
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```