# When to use 'Array.prototype' and when to use 'this' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's take this example from `The Good Parts` book:

```
Array.method('unshift', function () {
    this.splice.apply(this,[0,0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));
    return this;
});
```

Why did the author use `this.splice` in one place and `Array.prototype.slice` in other?

I tried swapping out `this` and `Array.prototype` with each other and got errors like the following:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

but I am still not sure about, how to know when to should use `this` or `Array.prototype`.

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7056925/476

Comment: This book was never a very good way to start with JavaScript, but now it's **severely** out of date (almost a decade old). I would strongly recommend that you find a better book to work with.

Comment: @torazaburo but I've picked this book up, after reading it as a recommended book from various sources.

Comment: Sorry, but this book is a collection of things which are irrelevant, obsolete, and in many cases just wrong (today). To make an analogy with English, it's closer to Chaucer than Shakespeare. It is primarily of archaeological interest. Most importantly, it completely omits very important things which are used by modern JS programmers every single day of their lives.

Comment: @torazaburo what other book would you recommend, provided that I'm already 9 chapters down from the book and this was my first encounter with JS?

Comment: @RajatSaxena eloquent js: http://eloquentjavascript.net

Comment: I don't know JS books very well, but "You Don't Know JS" seems to be well-regarded. Also "Speaking JavaScript" by Axel Rauschmayer (then follow that up with his ES6 book).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first call, `this` refers to the array on which `unshift` was called, and so it inherits `splice` from `Array.prototype`.

In the second call, though, the code uses `slice` on something that **isn't** an array (the `arguments` pseudo-array, which doesn't have a `slice` method). So in that case, Crockford accessed the method via `Array.prototype`.

Technically, he could have used `this.slice` in the second location, like this:

```
Array.method('unshift', function () {
    this.splice.apply(this,[0,0].concat(this.slice.apply(arguments)));
    return this;
});
```

...but it probably would have been misleading, since the second call has nothing to do with the current array referenced by `this`.

Comment: @RajatSaxena: My pleasure. I've removed something misleading above (the code is using `splice` and `slice`, but in my original answer, I'd mistakenly thought it used `splice` twice).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to visualise the relationship so you realise that in many cases we have `foo.bar === Foo.prototype.bar; // true`

[image: structure of prototypes]

On creation of an instance `foo`, the *prototype* property of the constructor `Foo` gets set as a special reference of `foo` (`__proto__`), where if you try to access a property which does not exist directly on `foo` the next place that property is looked for is through that reference.

This means when you expect `foo` to not have been modified in a way that would hide a property from that object, it doesn't really matter whether you try to look up via `foo.bar` or `Foo.prototype.bar` as it is the same thing.

However, as you can see, not *everything* will have the same `__proto__` path, so you couldn't assume `obj.slice` would exist, for example. This means if you don't have an *Array instance* but you want to *slice* it, you have to reference *slice* through a way you know exists, such as `Array.prototype.slice`