# Understanding common jQuery plugin boilerplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am trying to understand lines 10 and 12 of the below code, and have given my attempt to explain.  Please correct me as applicable.

```
//Line 10
return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
//Line 12
return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

Line 10.  If the argument provided to samplePlugin is a method, then make that method have the same `this` as is at the current script's location (i.e. Line 10), and ... Help! Where is `arguments` defined?  What is with the `call()`?  EDIT.  Okay, it seems `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` makes a real array out of all the arguments except the first one, however, still is a bit of a mystery.

Line 12.  Else if the argument provided to samplePlugin is an object or empty, then make the `init` method have the same `this` as is at the current script's location (i.e. Line 12), and ... Seems simpler, but still need help...

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init    : function (options) {return this.each(function () {/* ... */});},
        method1 : function ()        {return this.each(function () {/* ... */});},
        method2 : function ()        {return this.each(function () {/* ... */});}
    };

    $.fn.samplePlugin = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));   //Line 10
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);                                     //Line 12
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.samplePlugin');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery)
);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/3001761, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3001761.

Comment: @SLaks  Okay, that gets me going forward a little bit.  So, `arguments` is a keyword representing for an array like object holding the arguments passed to the function.  I will try to use this to better understand the rest.  I've used these few lines for years without really understanding them, and I feel that it is about time for this to stop.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You unraveled some parts yourself, but there's a non-trivial part of JavaScript function trickery involved. Let's put them apart:

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a “magic” variable inside function bodies, that offers access to the function arguments. It's simply there without declaration, and works like an array *but is no array* (will become important in a moment).

If you want to access the first argument to a function, `arguments[0]` is the place to look. In your specific function, that’s always identical to the variable `method`.

If you want to get any additional arguments (remember, that you can call JS functions with any number of arguments, not just the ones declared), a first pass might look like this:

```
arguments.slice(1)
```

but, remember, `arguments` is no array, it just looks like one. All `Array` methods are missing. So we need to [borrow them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects) from `Array.prototype`, where “real” arrays get them from:

```
Array.prototype.slice
```

To get `slice` to work with `arguments`, it must be called with `arguments` as `this`:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
```

([Read up on `Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))

So far so good.

Now, imagine the jQuery plugin gets called like this:

```
$('body').samplePlugin('method1', 'foo', 'bar');
```

The variable `method` is now `"method1"`. The first `if` is triggered, because there *is* a `method1` key in `methods`, and it's a function. So the function is called with all *remaining* arguments:

```
methods['method1'].apply(this, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Second branch: If the plugin is called like this:

```
$('body').samplePlugin({ foo: 'bar' });
```

then `method == { foo: 'bar' }` and we're landing in branch 2, since it's an object. The idea of the boilerplate author is, that in this case the `init` method should be called:

```
methods['init'].apply(this, arguments);
```

(`methods['init']` is the same as `methods.init` in JS.) We do not need the splicing trick from above, since `arguments[0]` is *not* any method name.

Comment: No problem. It's 11PM here, so I might not be around in a moment, but do post questions, if you have them.

Comment: Ah ha!  I just tested that `myRealArray.slice(1)` and `Array.prototype.slice.call(myRealArray,1)` result in the same.  Things are a little clearer!