# How can I call a method from a class without instantiating it?

Tags: javascript, oop

If you look at a framework like cocos2d-x, for example:

```
cc.Sprite.extend();
```

Sprite here is a class; how can I call one of its methods without instantiating it with the `new` keyword?

For example, if I have this class:

```
var superClass = function(){
    
    this.init = function(){
        console.log("new class constructed !")
    };

};
```

To call `init`, I must do this:

```
obj = new superClass();
obj.init();
```

But how can I call the function without needing to instantiate the class?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170332/how-is-this-possible-without-instantiating-new-ing-it-var-a-array-prototy

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### ES6 and newer:

Use the [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword. It's supported by [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static).

```
class SuperClass {
   static init() {
     console.log("new class constructed !")
   }
}

SuperClass.init();
```

### Older browsers:

There are different ways to achieve that. One option is to use an object literal.

**Object literal**:

```
var superClass = {
    init: function(){
        console.log("new class constructed !")
    }
};

superClass.init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ckgmb9fk/

However, you can still define an object using a function constructor and then add a static method to the "class". For example, you can do this:

```
var SuperClass = function(){};

SuperClass.prototype.methodA = function() {
    console.log("methodA");
};

SuperClass.init = function() {
    console.log("Init function");
}

SuperClass.init();

var sc = new SuperClass();
sc.methodA();
```

Note that the method `init` won't be available in the `SuperClass` instance object because it is not in the object prototype.

https://jsfiddle.net/mLxoh1qj/

**Extending prototype:**

```
var SuperClass = function(){};

  SuperClass.prototype.init = function() {
      console.log("Init");
  };

SuperClass.prototype.init();

var sc = new SuperClass();
sc.init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ayct1ry/

This solution is useful if you want to access the function `init` both from the `SuperClass` prototype and from an object instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the method this way, you will not be able to call it without instanciating the class, but you can achieve this by extending the prototype:

```
var superClass = function(){
};

superClass.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log("new class constructed !")
};

var obj = new superClass();
obj.init();
superClass.prototype.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `superClass` as namespace.

```
superClass = {
    init: function() { 
    }
}
```